# Java bluej . Get the next element from the arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, bluej

I am Beginner practicing java with bluej and trying to print the next element every time I use the getNext() method . I tried some options but they didn't work and now I am stuck . Here is my code:

```
public void getNextQuestion()
{
    int counter = 0;
    Iterator<Questions> it = this.questions.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
        Questions nextObject = it.next();

        System.out.println(counter+ ". " + nextObject.getDescription());


    }
}
```

Comment: What is a definition of Questions? What does 'the code doesn't work' mean? Is there some error? No output? Wrong output?

Comment: Looks fine to me. What exactly doesn't work? What is the this.questions field and how did you fill it? What looks fishy is that you use Iterator<Questions> instead of Iterator<Question>, or is that just a typo?

Comment: Your method probably prints all questions, not just the next one, because you use the 'while' loop.

Comment: @Alex I have two classes: The one  is Questions and the other one is test and I am  putting the created objects questions into the test list . I wrote down that I tried many options for doing this task but they didn't work but my code is working perfectly

Comment: @Alex Yes that is true . But i don't know how to print one by one

Comment: Your probably need to make the iterator the private field of your test class and initialize it properly. In this getNext question method you replace 'while'  with 'if'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you only want to print one question whenever `getNextQuestion` is called. In that case, you need to do this:

```
public class MyClass {

    int counter = 0;

    public void getNextQuestion()
    {
        Questions nextObject = questions.get(counter);
        counter = counter + 1;

        // If counter gets to the end of the list, start from the beginning.
        if(counter >= questions.size())
            counter = 0;

        System.out.println(counter+ ". " + nextObject.getDescription());
    }
}
```

As you can see, `counter` is now a global variable inside whaever class contains the method, and you don't need the iterator at all.